# I started working for a guy never filled out a W-4 and he is claiming to take taxes out of my check what should I do?

Tags: taxes

I started working for a guy never filled out a W-4 and he is claiming to take taxes out of my check what should I do?...  I started working for a small carpentry business about a week and a half ago I receive my first paycheck in cash because I started on a pay week and he pays every two weeks. I  talk to him about why I haven't filled out a W-4, or even an I-9 form, and he told me that his payroll company figures out how much to take out in taxes yet I never filled out paperwork. He has never even gotten a copy of my Social Security card or ID. Now he is saying that when I get my first paycheck he will figure out the percentage of taxes withheld and then I will owe him that from my first paycheck that he paid me in cash pretty much. It just seems very shady to me but I really need to work and I just don't want to get screwed in the end please give me any advice should I contact a lawyer?

Comment: Find a new job ASAP. If you got paid in cash, you didn't get paid. Once you have a new job, ask your local tax office (innocently) how to get details of your previous employment. Step back and watch the fall-out.

Comment: Go with your gut feeling.  This is shady.

Comment: You need some real advice from a qualified person, not random strangers on the internet, voting to close.

Comment: This is a legal advice question.  You didn't even tell us where you are.  In the US, there is some window to "catch up" on the paperwork, but you need to get advice from someone who is an expert in the law in your locality.

Answer (score 5):

If the owner of the company has paid you in cash and you have not filled out a W-4 or an I-9 form then the owner is hiding your employment from the government and (I am not a lawyer) most likely committing fraud in doing so.

This has many implications for you:

1. **You are probably not covered by workers compensation**. So if you are injured on the job you will be SOL.
2. **There is no paper trail of your wages.**  Thus you have no proof that you have been paid at all (or even the correct amount) for your labor (and/or that the correct deductions have been made).  You are now screwed by any situation that requires you to show proof of income and/or taxes.
3. When your employer ditches you, you would **not be able to collect any sort of unemployment benefit**.
4. If you continue to work under the table it could reflect badly on **how future employers perceive your integrity**.
5. **At the end of the year you will be responsible for paying all the taxes that were not with-held** from your wages.  Unless you are very strict with your budgeting you will find it hard to come up with the needed cash at tax time next year.
6. **You are also not paying into Social Security**, so you can nix that when it comes time to retire.

My opinion is that you need to separate yourself from this person ASAP.

Your employer's comment about the payroll company figuring out what to deduct sounds like pure BS as they need all the details that you haven't yet provided in order to officially make those deductions.

The comment about paying back the taxes from your first pay check also sound like BS as well.  If he has a payroll company doing his wages then why does he need to figure out what the deductions are?

The silver lining to quitting ASAP is that he will have a hard time proving that you need to pay him back for anything he claims you owe him - and he can't follow through with any legal action he will threaten you with because that will expose his fraudulent practices.

**I suggest you run to your local labor board and tell them exactly what is happening and how you are being treated.  You do not need to go to a lawyer on your own accord.**

---

**From the IRS**

[Topic 753 - Form W-4 – Employee's Withholding Allowance Certificate](https://www.irs.gov/taxtopics/tc753.html)

> When you hire an employee, you must have the employee complete a Form
>   W-4 (PDF), Employee's Withholding Allowance Certificate. Form W-4
>   tells you as the employer, the marital status, the number of
>   withholding allowances, and any additional amount to use when you
>   deduct federal income tax from the employee's pay. **If an employee
>   fails to give you a properly completed Form W-4, you must withhold
>   federal income taxes from his or her wages as if he or she were single
>   and claiming no withholding allowances.**

So even if your employer really wants to legitimately employ you he has already run afoul of IRS requirements.

---

**From the USCIS**

[WHO NEEDS THE FORM I-9?](https://www.uscis.gov/i-9-central/complete-correct-form-i-9/who-needs-form-i-9)

> All employers must complete and retain Forms I-9 **for every person they
>   hire for employment on or after Nov. 6, 1986**, in the United States as
>   long as the person works for pay or other type of compensation.

Comment: Those are good points, but #5 is actually incorrect. As a self-employed individual earning over a certain amount, he will owe taxes to the government each quarter.

Comment: @StephanBranczyk technically he may owe them each quarter, but you can get away with paying them only at the end of the year.  I speak from experience :D

Comment: I'd say look for a new job, and since this seems the USA, ask the inland revenue whether taxes have been paid on your behalf. In most countries about the worst crime you can commit (according to the tax office) is not paying the taxes for your employees.